# PHP PSR-0 Static Class

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoload-register, psr-0

I'm trying to rewrite an OO PHP site (that loosely follows an MVC structure) so it uses namespaces - and want to follow PSR-0.

In the current site I have a class (called APP) which is full of static methods that I call all over the place to handle things such as getting config data eg; `APP::get_config('key')`.

Obviously with namespacing, I would need to call `\TheNameSpace\App::get_config('key')`. I use this class frequently, so want to avoid having to prefix the namespace every time I use it. I do call methods in it from within other classes, which would usually be under a sub-namespace - so changing the namespace at the top of the file won't really work.

So, I guess my question is, what is the easiest way to have a 'global' class with methods that I can call anywhere without having to prefix with the namespace each time?

Comment: This has nothing to do with mvc or oop. You are just another person trying to make object-oriented-looking code while doing procedural programming.

Comment: And if you want to have a global class, why not put it in the global namespace? Remember that they are (actually) meant to eschew identifier conflicts, not for mercilessly wrapping everything without cause.

Comment: Essentially this is bad design - you should be injecting dependencies into the objects that need them, not calling an outside "god" class to fetch them.

Answer (score 0):

At top of your scripts add

```
use TheNameSpace\App as MyApp
```

for example. You can then use it like

```
app = new MyApp();
```

in your scripts. Of course you needn't to use an alias here. Just

```
use TheNameSpace\App
app = new App();
```

will work, too.

A global class that's implementing this one is bad style and you **shouldn't** do it like this:

```
class MyApp extends TheNameSpace\App { }

....
myApp = new MyApp();
```

Comment: What do you mean? In the use-statement? It's just an example to avoid interferences with other "used" namespaces containing a class with the same name. But thanks for the comment, I added a note for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Foo;
use Bar;
```

Then you do not have to do `\Bar\fn`

So in your case:

```
namspace Foo;
use TheNameSpace\App;

App::get_config('blah')
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the section in the php manual on using/aliasing namespaces.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

You can exclude the namespace by using "use". You can name it whatever you want.

```
use TheNamespace\App as App //You can name it anything here
App:config('key');
```